# Ways to Transfer Large Files over Wifi Local Network Faster and Stable?

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, networking, file-transfer

I have problem with transfer a large number of file over Wifi in LAN, often one of the computer will loss the Wifi signal or disconnected, and reconnect back again real quick.

and I also have problem with the speed, both run 54Mpbs Wireless card, and the max I can pull out between the two is about 950kb/s (I have a 54Mbps D-link router as well)

Is there a way to boost up the speed and have steady connection ?

Note:Both running Windows 7 RC

Answer (score 2):

I would look in to using Robocopy (buiit in windows) and you can [download a GUI here for it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.11.utilityspotlight.aspx) (There is a newer version, but I personally prefer this one)

Robocopy is very smart and can overcome drops and even computer restarts.

If you are constantly going to be sharing and syncronising two directories, you may want to take a look at alternative tools such as [Microsoft Sync Power Toy](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en), but I am not sure how that copes with restarts / drop outs, and if this is a one off, Robocopy is the tool for the job!

Comment: there is no status bar or anything showing the progress when I use Robocopy ?

Comment: GUI or command line?

Comment: the GUI has no progress showing